# How do I keep function and variable names from colliding?

Tags: powershell

I am making a script to install several programs.

Install.ps1

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
. "$here\includes\script1.ps1"
. "$here\includes\script2.ps1"

Write-Host "Installing program 1"

Install-ProgramOne

Write-Host "Installing program 2"

Install-ProgramTwo
```

script1.ps1

```
param (
    [string] $getCommand = "msiexec /a program1.msi /q"
)

function Get-Command {
    $getCommand
}

function Install-ProgramOne {
    iex $(Get-Command)
}
```

script2.ps1

```
param (
    [string] $getCommand = "msiexec /a program2.msi /q"
)

function Get-Command {
    $getCommand
}

function Install-ProgramTwo {
    iex $(Get-Command)
}
```

The `$getCommand` variable will get overwritten when both files are included.

There are namespaces in C# and modules in Ruby, but I cannot figure out how to keep namespaces separate in Powershell.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're wanting to do it this way?  I don't see the benefit of the added complexity even with Keith's fixes.  One script with an array of the commands to launch and a foreach loop to invoke each command in the array would do this in much less code.

Comment: Is this not a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586692/powershell-best-way-to-ensure-function-name-uniqueness ?

Comment: @CitizenRon I test drove my scripts using pester. They ended up with nearly the same structure, so I want to follow DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$getCommand` variable is not a variable per-se but a parameter. A parameter that has a default value specified.  That said, it isn't a great idea to have script parameters for a dot sourced script file.  These type of files usually just include a library of functions and shared/global variables.

A better approach in V2 and higher is to use a module.  A module is a container of variables and functions in which you control what is exported and what is private.  This is what I would do with your two scripts:

script1.psm1

```
# private to this module
$getCommand = "msiexec /a program1.msi /q"

function Get-Command {
    $getCommand
}

function Install-ProgramOne {
    iex $(Get-Command)
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Install-ProgramOne
```

script2.psm1

```
# private to this module
$getCommand = "msiexec /a program2.msi /q"

function Get-Command {
    $getCommand
}

function Install-ProgramTwo {
    iex $(Get-Command)
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function Install-ProgramTwo
```

The use like so:

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\script1.psm1
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\script2.psm1

Install-ProgramOne
Install-ProgramTwo
```

Comment: I like this approach. I didn't realize creating modules is this simple of a process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are "dot sourcing" your scripts instead of running them. This basically means "dump everything into the GLOBAL namespace". If you simply run the scripts instead of dot-sourcing them, then they each get their own local scope. In general, I think scripts with parameters should be run, not dot-sourced.

The problem with not dot-sourcing is that the functions you are declaring, by default, will go out of the scope when the script completes. To avoid this, you can define your function like this instead:

```
function global:Install-ProgramOne
{

}
```

And then merely run the script instead of dot-sourcing, and $getcommand will be local to each script you run.